# How to pick random element from array without repeating in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sample, rake-task

I am new to coding and am trying to learn Ruby. I am working in a Rake.
What should I use to ensure that the random selection never repeats the same response back to back?

array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

```
task :array do 
  array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  ap(array.sample) 
end
```

Comment: Could you say more (by editing your question) about what you mean by *never repeats the same response back to back*? Do you *never* want the same number twice? Or just not *twice in a row*?

Comment: not twice in a row. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `array.shuffle.each{|x|}` you can reorder the array, then traverse the new order, pulling items in a random order without repeating them.

Comment: This is not true if the array has repeated items, like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`, the case might be that 3 is pulled consecutive. For his answer he would need state.

Comment: I would just add a `.uniq` to clobber the duplicates, but the OP might indeed need almost-random-but-also-not-repeating-with-shuffled-duplicates, for whatever reason. Maybe they are building a radio station that plays songs in a random order, but at least by different artists...

Comment: Where did the other answer go? It may have handled the "no duplicates back-to-back" requirement. But as `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3].uniq == [3]` the OP must declare what they need there!