# Ruby Rake array selection task without duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, rake

I am trying to learn Ruby and am stuck on a rake task. Each time `rails fortune` is run, a different fortune should be displayed? 
What should I use to ensure that the random selection never repeats the same response back to back?

```
    desc "Print a random fortune"
    task :fortune do
       fortunes = [
         "Do not mistake temptation for opportunity",
         "A friend asks only for your time not your money",
         "Do not confuse recklessness with confidence",
         "Bide your time, for success is near",
         "Every day in your life is a special occasion"]

              ap(fortunes.sample)
         end
```

Should I use .each?

Comment: You mean each time you run the task? Is it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162191/how-to-pick-random-element-from-array-without-repeating-in-ruby?

Comment: yes since it I switching from a numerical array to a categorical array, '.uniq' is no longer applicable. I think i should be using '.each' but am not sure what would be the logic so that ap(fortune.sample) != previous ap(fortune.sample).

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish with the task. For what I understand this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51162207/5239030. Or you must spend some more words to clear your goal.

Comment: I was thinking about the fact that maybe you want in some way to store the result of each run. So on the second run the string already printed on the first run is skipped. And so on. I don't think you can pass variables between task calls. I suppose you should save to database.